# I want to distinguish mobile web address ,pc web page address

Tags: objective-c

I am giving a newslist link address by portal site open api.

I want to display these linked news on iPhone. Only mobile address link.

```
for(int i=0;i< [newsList count];i++)
{

  NewsItem *newsItem = (NewsItem *)[newsList objectAtIndex:i];
  const char *linkAddress = [newsItem.mLink UTF8String]; 

  if(~~~)     //->here. I want to check a mobile address.
  {
    [NaverNewslist addObject:newsItem];

  }
}
self.mNewsList=NaverNewslist;

self.mSearchKey=searchkey;

}
```

Address Example

- pc web page

http://openapi.naver.com/l?AAACXLOw6DMAwG4NOYEeVBIAwZKh5Tt57AJEagKoEG2orbN1DLkr/fll9vioeBrgFdQN1A14KWFxq4VaBZth8rmUDfLXvSYZAJOyK60bJh0I4JVGMhVUkKeVlZnk2RRjPt+wryBqJPff7mAT8Uc7v4tPA4hzQiocvDFED2fnEEsr0/WhCln13yRjZ5mx1PgbMyheU6sPo0/p2KK6aE/gGwxETByAAAAA==

- mobile web page

http://openapi.naver.com/l?AAACXLPQ6DMAwF4NOYETkJCenAUPEzdesJTGIEqgg00FbcvimVLPl7z/LzxfGooK3BFnCpoW3AqhM1XEuwmO3HylXgz5Y9+KgIpRuI/OCw761HSXoolDasSZjSiWyMPFTjvq+griC7NL/fPNCbY+6WORUzTSGtyOTzMAZQ3bx4BtXc7g1IM08+eWOXvE1epCDQpLCcBxQ2mf5GlBq10eYLRa/BpMgAAAA=

So, I think these addresses conclude a convertible infomation to mobile.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try decoding the base64-encoded data in these URLs to see if you an extract valuable information, like a "isMobile" flag.